# How to change the background behind of a jquery-ui modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, background, styles

I am using the smoothness theme. I only want to change the default background that it is too much soft.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to change the background of the window add style to the `.ui-widget-content` and if you need to change the overlay add style to `.ui-widget-overlay`

Answer (score 3):

You can customize JQuery UI theme in this url: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background style by customizing the `.ui-widget-overlay` class into the jqueryui css or using themeroller too, section `Modal Screen for overlays`